# CMake linking GoogleTest and UnitTests

Tags: c++, cmake

Im trying to setup GoogleTest to add some test on a Legacy-Code base.

So i downloaded the latest verson of GoogleTest and extracted it side by side to the legacy code and added an simple test to verify, that the installation/configuration is correct.

Every time i try to make the Project with CMake i end up with the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target RunUnitTests
[ 92%] Building CXX object Testing_Code/CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/test_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable RunUnitTests
CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/test_main.cpp.o: In function `main':
test_main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/test_main.cpp.o: In function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
test_main.cpp:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0x7): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
test_main.cpp:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0x10): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Testing_Code/CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'Testing_Code/RunUnitTests' failed
make[2]: *** [Testing_Code/RunUnitTests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:429: recipe for target 'Testing_Code/CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Testing_Code/CMakeFiles/RunUnitTests.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

(full output visible [here](https://gist.github.com/cedi/9203d899f66e367757c5))

Iv'e been searching for a fix for a long time. I have googled and read so many links at the internet that i lost the overview.
Im really new to CMake and think i miss something small but major...

My folder-hierarchy looks like the following:

```
+
|-+CMake
| |-run.sh
| |-BuildAll.sh
| |-CMakeLists.txt
|
|-+cpp-project
| |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-+work
| | |-CMakeLists.txt
| | 
| |-+include
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|
|-+GoogleTest
| |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-+googlemock
| |-+googletest
| |-RADME.md
| |-travis.sh
|
|-+Testing_Code
  |-CMakeLists.txt
  |-+test
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |-test.
```

To start the compiling i run `sh ~/code/CMake/run.sh` which looks like the following:

```
cp BuildAll.sh ./../BuildAll.sh
cp CMakeLists.txt ./../CMakeLists.txt
cd ..
sh BuildAll.sh $1
```

And BuildAll does some cleaning-stuff and generate some folders, etc.:

```
#!/bin/bash

alwaysCleanBuild=$1
control="control"
unittest_out="$control/test"
build="build"
include="$build/include"

if [ $alwaysCleanBuild = true ]; then
    if [ -d "$control" ]; then
        rm -r "$control"
    fi

    if [ -d "$build" ]; then
        rm -r "$build"
    fi
fi

mkdir $control
mkdir $build
mkdir $include

cd $build

cp -r ../GoogleTest/googletest/include/* ./include/
cp ../cpp-project/include/* ./include

cmake ..

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    make

    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
            ./../control/RunUnitTests
    fi
fi
```

New Folders in short:

- `control` is the output dir of the cpp-project libs/binarys/what ever you like to call the output ;)
- `build` is the CMake destination for generating the Makefile, etc.
- `build\include` is the public include-dir for the tests to access gtest and cpp-projects headders.

The CMake/CMakeLists.txt is copyed from the `BuildAll.sh` Script to the root-directory. So there is a 'root'-`CMakeLists.txt`. This CMakeLists specifies the `include_directories` and the output-directory('s):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(Test)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../control)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../control)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../control)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(cpp-project)
add_subdirectory(GoogleTest)
add_subdirectory(Testing_Code)
```

GoogleTest's CMakeLists are all untouched and they are running like a charm.
The cpp-projects CMakeFile are running very fine too and they output everything to the `control` directory. (I'm really satisfied with CMake. It's much quicker and simpler than the plain old Makefiles (in my oppinion) for the 'easy-beginner-steps').

The CMakeLists from `/Testing_Code/` also looks verry simple, but i think in there you will find my mistake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(Testing)

# Create main.cpp which uses gtest
file(WRITE test_main.cpp "#include <gtest/gtest.h>\n\n")
file(APPEND test_main.cpp "int main(int argc, char **argv)\n{\n")
file(APPEND test_main.cpp "    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);\n")
file(APPEND test_main.cpp "    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();\n")
file(APPEND test_main.cpp "}\n")

# build all tests
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test)
# ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test_2)
# ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test_3)

# build the test_main
ADD_EXECUTABLE(RunUnitTests test_main.cpp ${GTEST_INCLUDE})

# Link RunUnitTests with GoogleTest and cpp-project
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(RunUnitTests ${GoogleTest} ${cpp-project})
```

I can't find the mistake in here and i really hope that someone could help me with this.

Comment: Excuse me, you say "root CMakeLists.txt" but I cannot see it... the only one seems to be in /cmake right? Are you sure that the testing code is wrong? Could you please show a minimal example that generates the error?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy. I updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: The error that you are getting is a link error make sure that in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(RunUnitTests ${GoogleTest} ${cpp-project})` `${GoogleTest}` actually refers to the gtest library. We use an older version of google test and there it is just `gtest` and `gmock` for google mock (they are both integrated now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  in the cmake file of the testing code

```
include_directories(
    /path/to/googletest/include/folder )
```

EDIT:

Try this:

1) delete the lines

```
cp -r ../GoogleTest/googletest/include/* ./include/
cp ../cpp-project/include/* ./include
```

2) edit your cmake file from

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

to

```
    include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../include
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../googletest/include/)
  add_subdirectory(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/build
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 
 )
```

moreover since your CMakeLists.txt file is in the cmake folder it should be

```
add_subdirectory(../cpp-project)
add_subdirectory(../GoogleTest)
add_subdirectory(../Testing_Code)
```

rather than

```
add_subdirectory(cpp-project)
add_subdirectory(GoogleTest)
add_subdirectory(Testing_Code)
```

Comment: Sorry, that isn't doing the job for me. Same Error-Message. Any other ideass?

Comment: what did you write in place of /path/to/googletest/include/folder?

Comment: I added the absolute Path to the include-dir:
include_directories("/home/c3d1/code/GoogleTest/googletest/include")

I also tryed adding the absolute paths to the libgtest.a and libgtest_main.a with no success

Comment: actually I  realised that you are doing it by combining:
cp -r ../GoogleTest/googletest/include/* ./include/
cp ../cpp-project/include/* ./include

and 

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)

I am not convinced by this procedure, though.
Try to simplify the structure of your file. Can you try to compile it without using the shell script?